# Диалоговое окно на Python

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек

Хотел бы узнать существуют ли библиотеки для того чтобы вызвать или создать диалоговое окно с ошибкой (пример на фото), библиотека естественно для python.[image: диалоговое окно с ошибкой на win10]

Comment: Добавьте метку [tag:поиск-библиотек] и отредактируйте вопрос согласно её описанию

Comment: PyQt — реализация фреймворка Qt для языка Python.

Comment: А есть не просто pyqt, а именно чтобы как от системы было, в c# вроде была такая фича,  вот и ищу её в этом языке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `messagebox` из `tkinter`.

Он имеет 4 основных метода:

- showerror
- showwarning
- showinfo
- askyesno

Последнее название, на первый взгляд, выглядит странно. Так выглядит понятнее: `AskYesNo` или `Ask Yes/No`

Общая форма вызова:

```
method_name ("Имя окна", "Текст")
```

Вот пример кода:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw() # эта функция скрывает основное окно программы, можете её убрать


messagebox.showerror("Ошибка", "Текст ошибки")
messagebox.showwarning("Предупреждение","Текст предупреждения")
messagebox.showinfo("Информация","Полезная информация")
messagebox.askyesno("Выберите:", "Да / нет")
```

Метод `askyesno()` возвращает `True`, если пользователь нажал  "Да", и `False` в противном случае.

---

Выглядит не совсем как у системы, но тоже неплохо:

[image: msgbox]

Также значок в левом верхнем углу - это значок вашего приложения. Например, я добавил строки:

```
root.iconbitmap("icon.ico")
```

И получил:

[image: msgbox with icon]

Answer (score 2):

Если именно как от системы, то [wxPython](https://wxpython.org).

Answer (score 0):

Библиотека Tkinter, там можно создавать диалоговые окна.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox

top=Tk() 

top. geometry ("размер окна,например 100x100") 

messagebox.(askyesno, askquestion, askokcansel, showwarning, showerror,showinfo)("название окна", "текст окна") 

top. main loop()
```